# AngularJs always applies class last to body tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

We have the following in the `body` tag of our `index.html`:

```
<body ng-controller="AppController as app"  
      class="site-body {{$state.current.data.bodyClass}}">
```

We do this so we can apply classes to certain page from that page's route, as in:

```
  .state('about-theteam', {
    url: '/about/theteam',
    data: {
      pageTitle: 'The Team',
      access: 'private',
      bodyClass: 'about'
    },...
```

This works as expected.  Now, I am trying to apply another class to the body tag in `index.html` to apply a "theme" which needs to come last so it can override the default css:

```
<body ng-controller="AppController as app"  
      class="site-body {{$state.current.data.bodyClass}} theme-ocean">
```

However, to my chagrin the bound class is ignoring the order and coming last anyway, breaking the theme:

```
<body ng-controller="AppController as app" 
      class="site-body theme-ocean about">
```

Why is this?  Shouldn't the binding be in the order it is in the html, like when I do stuff like

```
 My name is {{name.first}} {{name.last}}, nice to meet you.
```

Why in the class attribute is it always appended to the end?

Note that I am trying to have a solution wherein my developers can simply add the theme to their main page and have the effect of the theme cascade through the css without any extra work on their part. This does work on all pages that do not have a `data bodyClass` in their routes.

Comment: it is likely caused because $state.current.data.bodyClass has no value until angular etc.. is loaded so its placed last? Just off the top of my head you might be able to create a custom directive that takes a list of classes and a list of dynamic classes (eg: about) and reorder them for you based on changes to the body's class tag.

Comment: Or another thing to try is to add all the classes in the {{ }} eg: class="{{"site-body " +  {{$state.current.data.bodyClass}} +"  theme-ocean"}" note the proper spaces. Without a demo project is hard for me to test.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you:

You can get the element "classList" and see the classes order.

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("site-body");
$scope.classList = element[0].classList;
```

I made a demo for you :
http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/14988/

In this example the "angular class" locate in the middle and not at the end as you said.